# Browser's repainting is very slow when using jquery addClass and removeClass

Tags: jquery, css, performance, browser

I have a page where I need to dynamically add or css classes. I have the following Jquery code in my page,

```
myElementsList.addClass('AClass').removeClass('BClass')
```

These css classes will change the color and background color of my elements. The problem is that this takes 2 or 3 seconds to repaint the browser.

If i use css classes which does not eXist(or does not repaint the browser) then it will eecute very quickly.

```
myElementsList.addClass('NotEXistClassA').removeClass('NotEXistClassB')
```

Any suggestion will be welcome?

**Edit**:

The way I solve this issue by changing the first 20 rows first and changing the remaining using a timer. I am also reseting this timer every time if the events raised again before the timer elapased.

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: what browser? what OS? are there flash or large images defined by those CSS classes?

Comment: So that would mean that it’s not the add/removeClass that is slow, but the way you repaint the browser, right?

Comment: @MarekSebera Both in IE and FF. THere is nothing Flash or any image in my sample. Just a table with 5000 rows

Comment: Can you provide some example on jsfiddle.net or so?

Comment: So the title is a bit misleading, as the reasons for the slow performance has little to do with the code you provided...

Comment: the 5000 rows may be the reason it is slow, if it were only 10 it would be fast.

Comment: @jackJoe Yes you are write even if the rows are just 100. Then it works very fast

Comment: @MarekSebera jsfiddle.net is hanging out when i paste the html. Don't know why. But iw ill try again

Comment: @MarekSebera Here ia an sn sample I uploaded, http://www.mediafire.com/?9k9u0a8866tmh2b

Comment: there you have it, it's teh amount of rows that is slowing down the script, don't expect miracles. After looking at your example code, my only "solution"/suggestion, is to divide the result into several pages, this way, maybe use only 50 results per page, the speed will improve greatly.

Comment: @jackJoe it's not the script problem, it's the browser repainting. See my question CAREFULLY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to get the browser to do two things at once, which both require it to repaint the same things.

But in fact you can achieve what you want to do (change the colour of the rows) by only doing one of the two actions.

The basic change you need to make is not to have a style for "not-selected" and another style for "selected", but instead to have one for "default" and one for "selected".

Then you can have the "default" style to set the standard colour, and simply add the "selected" style to override it; you don't need to remove the default style, as the selected one will override it.

Here's a simple bit of CSS to get you started:

```
.grid tr {
    background: #FFFFFF;  /*default white background*/
}

.grid tr.selected {
    background: #222222;
}
```

...and the script would just do `addClass('selected')` when you select it, and `removeClass('selected')` when you deselect it.

There really is no need for a `not-selected` class at all.

That simple change will remove a full half of the work that your program is doing when you toggle the selection, and in fact it will quite possibly speed it up by more an 50% due to it not having to do multiple re-paints on the same elements.

That will certainly get you going a bit faster. It isn't the whole story as to why your page is slow, but it will certainly help a lot.

Comment: Thanks it improves the speed very much.

Answer (score 0):

First remove class then assign new class

```
myElementsList.removeClass('BClass').addClass('AClass');
```

I think this may help you.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not help.